# How can I determine the data type of a SQL Server table row using VB.Net

Tags: odbc, oledb, sqlclient, getschema

I am working on some code that allows the client to connect to a variety of external data sources, including OLEDB, ODBC and SQL Server. In my VB.NET code, if I set up a connection using `system.data.oledb` or `system.data.odbc`, I can use the `system.data.oledb.oledbType` or `system.data.odbc.odbcType` methods to test for Integer or Double data types.

For example, in the code snippet below, `dr` is a data row from a data table populated using the OLEDB connection, `GetSchema` method.

```
--- Start Example-------
If dr("Data_Type") = System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer Then
  ...
End
--- End Example-------
```

There is a similar solution for `system.data.odbc`.

However, I can't seem to find a way to get the data type from a data row table populated from the `GetSchema` method of a `SQLClient` connection.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that loads a DataGridView. Instead of using a form you'll just load a local DGV or use DBSchema which is a DataTable.

```
    Private Sub DataDictionaryToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataDictionaryToolStripMenuItem.Click
    If g.DBSchema Is Nothing Then
        Using con As New SqlConnection(g.OISConnectString)
            con.Open()
            g.DBSchema = con.GetSchema("Columns") ' full DB Schema
        End Using
    End If
    Dim frm As New frmSearch2
    frm.inDataView = New DataView(g.DBSchema) ' dv
    frm.inSQLName = "Database Schema"
    frm.Show()
End Sub
```

If you have an existing DataTable (e.g. g.DBSchema) you can use this:

```
    For Each col As DataColumn In g.DBSchema.Columns
        Debug.Print(col.DataType.ToString)
    Next
```

But this will return the ADO DataType (I think) and not the SQL data type.

Comment: I am already getting the schema of the SQL data source into a DataTable. What I am looking for is how to examine the rows of a table and identify if a specific row (column) is a numeric data type. I can do this for OLEDB and ODBC data sources using a comparison to a if (data_row("Data_Type") = System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer or if (data_row("Data_Type") =System.Data.Odbc.OdbcType.Integer. What I need is a similar method of checking the data type for a SQLClient based connection.

Comment: Your are going to have to refine the original post - please provide some code you are having problems with - not code that works in another context. Also state if you are trying to get the SQL data type or the datatable column data type - they are not the same thing.